# jQuery back button does not work properly after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

On my jQuery mobile app;

On menu.html and **inside body** I do something like this to go help.html;

```
....

$(document).off('pageinit', '#menupage').on('pageinit', '#menupage', function() {

    $(document).off('click', '#help').on('click', '#help', function(){
            $.mobile.changePage("help.html", {
                reloadPage: true,
                transition: "flip",
                reverse: false
            });
        });
}

....

<li><a id="help" href="#" role="link" data-role="none">
                        <div class="img help"></div>
                        <div class="menuTitle langMenuItem3">Help</div>
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
</a></li>
```

Then on the help.html page I have a back button like this to go back to menu.html:

```
<header data-role="header">
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="button" data-role="none">
        <div class="arrow_reverse"></div><span class="langBack">Terug</span>
    </a>
    <div class="pageTitle">Over deze app</div>
</header>
```

My problem is this works under normal conditions, **BUT** if I make a **refresh** on menu.html, then go to help.html **and then** go back to menu again, menu.html does not load properly, I can see the page visually loaded ok but on firebug I see that some necessary javascripts inside   tags does not hit anymore, It never hits any javascripts anywhere on menu.html anymore, just loads the previous html from cache thats all. Also the page title of menu.html does not change correctly and stays as "Help" after that point.

my full menu.html looks like this;

http://jsfiddle.net/M5CYZ/

Any ideas?

Comment: if you back and further several times without refresh, you encounter the same?

Comment: @Omar yes..but if i make a refresh on help.html problem solves!

Comment: This is weird..the problem is within menu.html then. Can you post its' markup? are using `data-dom-cache` or `data-prefetch`?

Comment: @Omar sorry what are they?:)

Comment: lol, things that cause headache _sometimes_ ;) could you post markup and code of menu.html? or a fiddle. [dom-cache and prefetch](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-cache.html).

Comment: @Omar tnx I copy paste some code here from menu.html http://jsfiddle.net/M5CYZ/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27645/discussion-between-omar-and-spring)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way.

Give back button an `ID`

```
<a href="#" id="backbtn" class="button"> 
 <div class="arrow_reverse"></div><span class="langBack">Terug</span> 
</a>
```

and then add the below code in *help.html*

```
$('#backbutton').off('click').on('click', function () { 
 $.mobile.changePage("menu.html", { 
  reloadPage: true, 
  transition: "flip", 
  reverse: true 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a dot (`.`) for the `on()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wild guess but according to your code this is a normal behaviour.

jQuery Moible event pageinit will trigger only once during the initial page load and unless page is refreshed (manually, with rel="external" or in your case reloadPage="true") it will never trigger again.

If you want javascript to execute again each time page is visited then use pagebeforeshow event instead. As seen in your example, removing pageinit and adding it back will not help you.

If you want to find more, read my other answer/article about page events: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**

And here's an example to prove my point: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q3Usv/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){       
    alert('Pageinit');
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    alert('Pagebeforeshow');
});
```

Comment: another thing is if i make a refresh on help.html and go back then problem solves..any ideas?

Comment: as i said my code works good but when i make a refresh manually on menu.html then this problem happens

Comment: Interesting. Can you try something else. Replace your help.html with this button code:     <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="button" data-role="none" data-ajax="false">
        <div class="arrow_reverse"></div><span class="langBack">Terug</span>
    </a>